# Strange State / UseEffect Behaviour using NextJS Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am experiencing so really strange behaviour in this personal project i am doing. In short it is a recipe website, with buttons at the top that direct to different pages that ultimately query firebase and pull down a query.

Index.js File - Queries Firestore passes props to FoodCard.js to Render a list of all recipes
breakfast.js - Queries Firestore with a filter and passes same props down (with different results) to FoodCard.js

**Behaviour**
When i click on Breakfast JS, it brings up my list of filtered results correctly, however when i click my Next Link "Welcome to the Family Heirloom" to return to the index the first click doesnt respond, then the second click returns home, but with the filtered breakfast result concatonated with all the original results (effectively causing duplicates)[Index on First Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d7BV.jpg)

[Breakfast filter successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7LMn.jpg)
[index with the now duplicate pancake result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjXxs.jpg)

I have messed about wondering if useEffect is not getting triggered which you may see in the code, but that didnt seem to work, so at a loss
Index.js

```
    import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/dist/client/router'

import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal'
import FoodCard from '../src/ui/FoodCard.js'
import firebase from '../firebase/initFirebase'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  mainContainer: {

  }
}))

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'red',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

export default function CookBook() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  const classes = useStyles()
  const theme = useTheme()

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRecipesFromFirebase = [];
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
      .collection("recipes")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(querySnapshot)
          getRecipesFromFirebase.push({
            ...doc.data(), //spread operator
            key: doc.id, // `id` given to us by Firebase
          });
        });
        setRecipes(getRecipesFromFirebase);

        console.log(recipes);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [loading, router.events]); // empty dependencies array => useEffect only called once

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Loading Data
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>)
  }

  return (


    <FoodCard recipes={recipes} />

  )

}
```

_app.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import theme from '../src//ui/theme';
import createEmotionCache from '../src/createEmotionCache';
import Header from '../src/ui/Header';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import { Link as MUILink } from '@mui/material/'
import NextLink from 'next/link'

// Client-side cache, shared for the whole session of the user in the browser.
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

export default function MyApp(props) {

  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;



  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>

      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Header />
        <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center" direction="column" >
          <Grid item>
            <NextLink href="/" passHref>
              <MUILink underline="none" color="secondary" variant="h1">
                Welcome To the Family Heirloom
              </MUILink>
            </NextLink>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  emotionCache: PropTypes.object,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Breakfast.js

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import FilterMains from '../../src/ui/FilterMains'
import { useRouter } from 'next/dist/client/router'
import FoodCard from '../../src/ui/FoodCard'

import {
    getFirestore, collection, query, where, onSnapshot
} from 'firebase/firestore'


const Breakfast = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;

    const [breakfastloading, setBreakfastLoading] = useState(true);
    const [breakfastRecipe, setBreakfastRecipe] = useState([]);

    const db = getFirestore()

    const docRef = collection(db, 'recipes')
    //Query
    const q = query(docRef, where("category", "==", 'Breakfast'))

    useEffect(() => {
        const getBreakfastFromFirebase = [];
        onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                getBreakfastFromFirebase.push({ ...doc.data() })
            })
            setBreakfastRecipe(getBreakfastFromFirebase)
            setBreakfastLoading(false)
            console.log(breakfastRecipe)

        })

    }, [breakfastloading, router.events]);

    if (breakfastloading) {
        return (
            <h2>Loading Data</h2>
        )
    }

    return (
        <FoodCard recipes={breakfastRecipe} />

        // <FoodCard recipes={recipes} />

    )

}
export default Breakfast
```

FoodCard.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Link from 'next/link'
import CardActionArea from '@mui/material/CardActionArea';

function FoodCard(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                < Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center" direction="row" >
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        {props.recipes.map((recipe) => (
                            <Link href={`/recipes/${recipe.key}`} passHref>
                                <Grid key={recipe.id} item xs={12} md={6}>

                                    <Card elevation={3} sx={{ maxWidth: 400 }}>
                                        <CardActionArea>
                                            <CardHeader
                                                titleTypographyProps={{ fontWeight: "Bold" }}
                                                title={recipe.title}
                                                subheader={recipe.description}
                                            />

                                            <CardMedia
                                                component="img"
                                                height="194"
                                                image="/assets/comingsoon.jpg"
                                                alt="Mac and Cheese"
                                            />
                                        </CardActionArea>
                                    </Card>

                                </Grid>

                            </Link>

                        ))}
                    </Grid>

                </Grid >
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
export default FoodCard
```

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it, although i can't fully explain why. In my learning i used two different methods for interfacing with firebase. The first method on the index page was what i would call the older way. The second method i used was in all of my other files, specific to interfacing with Version 9 of Firebase.

from this:

```
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
      .collection("recipes")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(querySnapshot)
          getRecipesFromFirebase.push({
            ...doc.data(), //spread operator
            key: doc.id, // `id` given to us by Firebase
          });
        });
```

to this:

```
 let getRecipesFromFirebase = [];
    getDocs(colRef)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let getRecipesFromFirebase = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          getRecipesFromFirebase.push({ ...doc.data(), key: doc.id })
        })
        setRecipes(getRecipesFromFirebase);

        console.log(recipes);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
      })
```

Would love somebody more knowledgable (3 months into React) than myself to tell me as to why though.